# Error on DB connection when trying to build forms and bpm from deployment->docker

Tags: formsflow.ai, formsflow

when i tried to build formsflow-form,formflow-bpm ,keycloak etc from deployment docker i got error saying "could not connect to database". But i can build all these seperately.
[image]

Comment: What was the command you used to bring up the server?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like from the error logs you are missing environment variables for database which is required to set up forms-flow-ai in Docker. You can checkout the [Installation steps of formsflow.ai solution in docker and follow along it to resolve the issue.](https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai/tree/master/deployment/docker#installation-steps)

Comment: i copied the same command which mentioned in github.I restarted my system and now  it worked